# What does kExtAudioFileError_AsyncWriteTooLarge(-66569) returned by ExtAudioFileWriteAsync mean?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-audio

I can't find any info about `OSStatus = -66569` returned by `ExtAudioFileWriteAsync`, except its enum tag: `kExtAudioFileError_AsyncWriteTooLarge`.

Right now I'm asking not why I get this error, but what does it really mean? Because I get this status, even if I try to pass any packets quantity more than zero...

For example: `ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(MyExtAudioFileRef, 1, &MyAudioBufferList);`

Thanks a lot in advance! =)

Comment: "no one? anyone?" (c) tyrion lannister =))